# On Prem AD Impersonation with Azure SSO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an application that updates On Prem AD as the Logged in User using impersonation. We're using custom login so the application have the credentials needed to fully impersonate the user.

Now we are trying to implement Azure SSO, but the application no longer has the credential to impersonate the user.

Is there a way to use Azure SSO and impersonate the logged in user in on prem AD?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since you are using custom logins, you might want to provide a [mre].

Comment: Thank you, we're actually trying to remove the custom login and just use azure sso.